# Nested datagrid : setting focus on the inside datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a datagrid with a single column rendered with another datagrid. I'm doing this to implement a rowspan-like display (with a hbox beneath the child datagrid) showing messages under each row.
When I tab and reach the end of a row, I want the focus to pass to the next row i.e the next child datagrid and on a specific cell of that row. 
This is the simplified code calling the renderer :

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%"
                 showHeaders="false"
                 selectable="false"
                 id="ParentDatagrid"
                 dataProvider="{arrayActs}"
                 paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0"
                 variableRowHeight="true">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="components.ColumnRendererDatagrid"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

And the renderer (ColumnRendererDatagrid) code :

```
<mx:DataGrid 
    id="dgLocal" width="100%" height="23" borderSides=""
    dataProvider="{data}" showHeaders="false"
    editable="true" selectable="false">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:HRule width="100%" />
<mx:Label id="message" text="Error Message" width="100%" />
```

For the moment, I'm using the following snippet in ColumnRendererDatagrid to check when tabbing reaches the end of the row and bubble up the event :

```
if(dgLocal.editedItemPosition.columnIndex == 13){
                dispatchEvent(new Event(MOVE_FOCUS_DOWN, true));
```

From there I'm struggling on how to drill down into the renderer to set the focus once the higher component get this event. Any help would be really appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution I came up with. This is the code in the parent's event handler (handling the MOVE_FOCUS_DOWN):

```
//Find the postition of the item that sent the event :
for each( var row:Object in ParentDatagrid.dataProvider ) {     
                if( (event.target as ColumnRendererDatagrid).data == row) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            } 

//Get the renderer of the next item :
  var render:IListItemRenderer = ParentDatagrid.itemToItemRenderer(arrayActes.getItemAt(i+1));
  (render as ColumnRendererDatagrid).dgLocal.editedItemPosition = {rowIndex:0, columnIndex:1}
```

(obviously checks should be made in real code to see if the next object exists) which is of type ColumnRendererDatagrid. From there I just set the focus/editing position.